# Django testing - test the view which handles an ajax call

Tags: ajax, django, testing

In testing Django, the view is returning 200 code but not sending any error message related.

```
def ajax_view(request):
    msg = ''
    if request.is_ajax():
        username = request.POST['username']
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        msg = 'user exists'

    return HttpResponse(msg)
```

In tests.py

```
    response = self.client.post(reverse('ajax_view'), data={'username': 'hello'})       
    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
    self.assertContains(response, 'exist')
```

It seems it is not going through the request.is_ajax().. How can I mock the ajax call in Django testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs on the test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#making-requests) mention this; you need to pass the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header, which you can do as a keyword argument.

Also, if you pass `content_type` as 'application/json', Django will automatically serialize to JSON. So:

```
response = self.client.post(
    reverse('ajax_view'),
    data={'username': 'hello'},
    content_type='application/json',
    HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest'
)
```

Comment: I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure this will resolve the entire issue but your method may be expecting the data in a json format:

```
json_data = json.dumps({'username': 'hello'})
response = self.client.post(reverse('ajax_view'), data=json_data)
```